# Oracle PL/SQL, from keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, sql-merge

Im working with Oracle Apex and my plsql statement doesnt work.

I checked the Oracle documentation and im pretty sure the syntax of my code is fine and it should work.
The APEX code validation tells me the code is fine as well.

```
merge into PY_BEWERTUNG b
using (select :P52_BEWERTUNG as rating, :APP_USER as user, :P52_ID as id from DUAL) src
    on (src.user = b.NUTZER and src.id = b.LOESUNG_ID)
when matched then update set 
    b.BEWERTUNG = src.rating
when not matched then 
    insert (NUTZER, LOESUNG_ID, BEWERTUNG, FAVORIT) 
    values (src.user, src.id, src.rating, 0);
```

The "from DUAL" is at the right place, so why do I get an "ORA-00923 from keyword not found where expected" error ? 
Any ideas?

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword. Try `:APP_USER as app_user`

Comment: Oh wow .. Can't believe i missed that, thanks.

Comment: are you running the code on APEX page or in stored procedure/function?